# Media file path generation

Tags: shopware6

is there a way to migrate existing media files into new structure after changing

```
shopware:
    cdn:
        strategy: id
```

to

```
shopware:
    cdn:
        strategy: plain
```

and are there any required steps for new uploads to be stored the “plain” way? As far as I can tell, my newly uploaded files are not affected by the config change.
Additionally: are there any drawbacks of using the plain strategy?

My reasoning behind the change is to speed up rsync of ~40GB of files, when they are stored on one level as public/media/<filename.xy> instead of the "default" nested approach. Would that even gain me speed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no readily available method to migrate existing files when changing the strategy.

The whole idea of the `id` strategy is to make lookups faster. So the drawback of using the `plain` strategy would be performance loss with a huge amount of files within a single directory.

While `rsync` probably doesn't profit from the `id` strategy as it will have to traverse the directories anyways, I couldn't find any reports of the amount of directories impacting the speed in a significant way.

Comment: It would be very helpful to have a migrate command like in SW5. 

bin/console sw:media:migrate

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-media-service/

Is something planned?

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful to have a migrate command like in SW5.

bin/console sw:media:migrate

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/shopware-5-media-service/

Is something planned?